# async/await function not always behave correctly

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

I'm developing a react-native/nodeJS project and I'm experiencing issues with the Axios API call to my backend using async/await functions.

Here's the code:

```
const TimeTable = () => {
  const [attendedCourses, setAttendedCourses] = useState([]);
  const [courseSchedules, setCourseSchedules] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserCourses();
    getCourseSchedule();
    console.log(courseSchedules);
  }, []);

  const getCourseSchedule = async () => {
    for (const item of attendedCourses) {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/api/lesson/findById/${item.courseId}`);
        setCourseSchedules((prev) => [
          ...prev,
          {
            id: res.data._id,
            name: res.data.name,
            schedule: [...res.data.schedule],
          },
        ]);
      } catch (err) {
        const error = err.response.data.msg;
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };

  const getUserCourses = async () => {
    const userId = "12345678"; //hardcoded for testing purpose
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`/api/users/lessons/${userId}`);
      setAttendedCourses(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      const error = err.response.data.msg;
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (...); //not important

};

export default TimeTable;
```

The method `getUserCourses()` behave correctly and returns always an array of objects which is saved in the `attendedCourses` state. The second method `getCourseSchedule()` doesn't work correctly. The console.log() in the useEffect() prints most of the time an empty array. 
Can someone please explain to me why? Thank you!

Comment: Because you're logging the value before you've received any response from the server.

Comment: Try `await getUserCourses()` and `await getCourseSchedule()`

Answer (score 1):

While the method is async, the actual useEffect is not dealing it in asynchronous manner and won't await till you reach the `console.log` in the useEffect. If you put the console.log inside the `getCourseSchedule` method and log the result after the await, it'll show you correct result every time.

You are confusing the async nature of each method. Your code does not await in the useEffect, it awaits in the actual method while the rest of the useEffect keeps executing.

If you really want to see the result in useEffect, try doing:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const apiCalls = async () => {
    await getUserCourses();
    await getCourseSchedule();
    console.log(courseSchedules);
  }

  apiCalls()
})
```

Comment: I use the console.log just for testing. I actually need to execute a function after the `getUserCourses()` and `getCourseSchedule()` have completed their work. Anyway, I'm continuing to see an empty array in the console. Any other solutions? @Danyal

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` has an empty array as dependencies that means it is run only onetime in before initial render when the `courseSchedules` has initial value (empty array)

To see the `courseSchedules` when it change you should add another `useEffect` like this:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(courseSchedules);
  }, [courseSchedules]);
```